# Calculate Intake Manifold Absolute Pressure from MAF Engine using OBD Data

Tags: obd-ii, air-intake, obd, intake-manifold, engine-load

I need to calculate Intake Manifold Absolute Pressure from OBD Data. I have Toyota Corolla GLI 2010 Model. This car has MAF engine which does not return Intake Manifold Absolute Pressure. Where'as I got Intake Manifold Absolute Pressure from Honda Car Because Honda Car's engine was MAP Type.

Can Anybody Provide me the formula for calculating Intake Manifold Absolute Pressure using OBD data.

Comment: There is no such formula. Your best bet is to add in your own MAP sensor.

Comment: or use a vacuum gauge since map is baro minus gauge vacuum.

Comment: I just want to calculate it for my Machine learning. I dont want to install a part in my vehicle.